# forward declare a template alias

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I have an aliased template, defined with the using directive:

```
template<typename A>
using T=TC<decltype(A::b),decltype(A::c)>;
```

Does C++11 offer a mechanism to forward declare this template alias `T`?

I tried:

```
template<typename> struct T;
```

and:

```
template<typename>
using T;
```

but both return compiler errors ("conflict with previous declaration"). I am using gcc 4.8.

What is the syntax to get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

What you want to do is forward declare `TC`, then define `T` immediately below it.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct TC;

template<typename A>
using T=TC<decltype(A::b),decltype(A::c)>;
```

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I will give the question a few more minutes in hope for another answer, and probably accept this answer afterwards.