# How to forward declare an aliased template in c++

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

I have the following aliased template:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using MyVector = std::vector <T>;
```

How can i forward declare `MyVector`?

```
template <typename T>
class MyVector;
```

does not work for me.

Comment: Why do you want to forward declare a type alias?

Comment: You cannot. How do you want to use it?

Comment: Change typename to class: `template <class T>
class MyVector`

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı [That makes no difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023977/c-difference-of-keywords-typename-and-class-in-templates).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forward declare a template alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304468/forward-declare-a-template-alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot forward declare an using declaration.
Anyway, you can declare forward a sort of *traits* as it follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename>
struct MyStuff;

template<typename T>
auto f() { return typename MyStuff<T>::MyVector{}; }

template<typename T>
struct MyStuff {
    using MyVector = std::vector<T>;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f<int>()), std::vector<int>>::value, "!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get away with making it a type, which you will be able to forward-declare:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyVector: std::vector<T> {};
```